# A word puzzle I made

Tags: word

You'll toss me on the ground
I'll jump at you just in case
You'll help me off a horse
I'll lift you up instead
You'll mount me on your boat
I'll shout the time for you
You'll wager your house with me
Then take things back illegally

Who/what am I?

Hint 1:

> The answer is a single word.

Hint 2:

> You can wager other things as well, not just your house. Usually it'll just be money.

Hint 3:

> The ground will usually be grass, though I've seen people toss it on gravel many times.

Hint 4:

> I won't literally shout the time out loud, just make loudly sure you know it.

Hint 5:

> The wager will take place in a specific family of casino/gambling games.

Hint 6:

> I'll lift you up a short distance off the ground. You won't fly.

Hint 7:

> You'll usually mount me on warships, rather than lowly boats, and you'll take me off while under way.

Hint 8:

> This item is tossed on the ground as part of a game.

Hint 9:

> The answer is a four-letter word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is

> <s>Horseshoe</s>  
>  Jack

You'll toss me on the ground

> This refers to the "jack" (target ball) in a game of bowls

I'll jump at you just in case

> Referring to "Jumping jacks"

You'll help me off a horse

> Refers to a well-known phrase about bad grammar: "Helping your Uncle, Jack, off a horse"

I'll lift you up instead

> Referring to a car jack, designed to lift a car to enable repairs

You'll mount me on your boat

> Refers to a jack staff, mounted on the bow of a boat to fly a flag

I'll shout the time for you

> Jack refers to the figure of a man striking the bell on a clock.

You'll wager your house with me

> Black Jack

Then take things back illegally

> Jack is a verb which means to take things back illegally.

This now fits with all the hints also.

Answer (score 2):

answer:

> a traitor of a criminal gang
>
>  a criminal will attack a traitor thus toss it on the ground
>  a traitor will jump back at you when the betrayal is revealed
>  the traitor will pretend to receive help off a horse whilst capturing you instead.
>  a traitor is someone you used to  trust as a companion hence "mount on the boat"
>  The traitor is thought to help organise plans for the other  but will make it obvious for the person's enemies.
> the next line either refers to betting in bridge card game (thus "with me" as a partner or sharing houses literally using mortgage contracts.
>  Finally the last line refers to the other person stealing from the traitor's house which is against the contract that the reader has made.

Comment: This is not the direction I was thinking about.

also, perhaps you should use the spoiler tag >! to hide the answer, just in case it was the right one... I'll add a hint to the question now.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling SE. Here are the reasons why it is not a good answer. 1. You didn't use spoiler tag. 2. It is not lateral thinking question and your answer is full of it. 3. It's answer is a word. You should have a look at [answer]

Comment: @scf thank you for letting me know and sorry I am new here I will not repeat the mistake. In future I will think more carefully.

Comment: @manshu this isn't really lateral thinking...

Comment: @question_asker [google it](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=what+is+lateral+thinking&oq=what+is+lateral+thinking&aqs=chrome..69i57.4602j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)... but i preferred searching in my dictionary which told me that lateral thinking is "A heuristic for solving problems; you try to look at the problem from many angles instead of tackling it head-on"

Comment: @manshu right, and this is not that. "Lateral thinking" refers to a very specific type of problem, not just interpreting wordplay, like we're seeing here and on all riddles

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be a

> ball

although I'm still missing some explanations.

You'll toss me on the ground

> There are games where balls are tossed, especially ones with grass fields

I'll jump at you just in case

> A ball thrown at the ground jumps back

You'll help me off a horse

> No idea about this one

I'll lift you up instead

> A ball can lift a person, if it is a gym ball for sitting on, or a child playing in the pool and climbing onto an inflatable ball

You'll mount me on your boat

> You mount cannons, which shoot cannonballs

I'll shout the time for you

> Again, no idea here

You'll wager your house with me

> You wager on a ball when playing roulette

Then take things back illegally

> Also no good guess here

I hope others can provide ideas for the missing clues if they agree my guess fits.

Comment: Your answer is surprisingly close to the right one, though for all the wrong reasons :)  Nice try!